# Backbone sorting only apply to views

Tags: javascript, performance, sorting, backbone.js

I'm developing a sorting function using backbone. And I looked into some of the suggestions they all seem to recommend using `views` to listen to `collections` and let `views` render after `collections` are sorted. Which doesn't apply to my case for two reasons:

1. My sorting function only needs to rearrange the presented data, this new 'sorted' dataset doesn't need to persist
2. If I use a significantly big amount of data, the `render() --> sortCollection() --> render()` process would take too long.

Therefore I'm wondering if there is any way to ONLY sort on the view layer? Which doesn't require much re-rendering and still allows me to interact with each subview (say a table row)?

Comment: You might want to look at Backbone.ModelBinder-- their most recent releases will properly re-order views on sort without wasting cycles re-rendering. https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder

Answer (score 0):

Bind your view to collection 'change'
When your collection is updated your view execute a function parse then render.

Parse/sort in your view on collection update just before rendering.